# The Angular nebular calendar shows wrong week number when setting locale to 'sv'

Tags: angular, nebular

I have an angular application which uses the nebular calendar component. I have a problem, when I set my locale to 'sv', the week numbers being displayed were greater than 1 compared to the should be the correct current week number.

**Showing wrong week numbers:**

[image]

**The correct week numbers:**

[image]

Might someone could help me with this. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

week numbers are calculated differently for different locales. the US for example doesnt know a week 53, but most european locales do. It looks to me like this is actually correct